# Laravel conditional belongsTo

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I have a component_events table with an id (primary key), an event_id, and an event_type (string).

I want to make sure that if the wrong relationship is called that it doesn't return an erroneous record.

The only thing I've been able to come up with is (in the ComponentEvent model) ...

```
public function AircraftEvent()
{
    return ($this->event_type === 'flight') ? $this->belongsTo('AircraftFlightEvent', 'event_id') : $this->belongsTo('AircraftMaintenanceEvent', 'event_id');
}
```

There has to be a better way!

I've looked at the docs for polymorphic relationships but I don't understand it and it seems like a "many" relationship which in my case it's not.

I would prefer to have to two separate relationships ...

```
public function AircraftFlightEvent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('AircraftFlightEvent', 'event_id');
}

public function AircraftMaintenanceEvent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('AircraftMaintenanceEvent', 'event_id');
}
```

But if someone accidentally calls the wrong relationship it could return an erroneous record.

I have tried adding ->where('flight', $this->event_type) but that looks at the columns from the related table not the component_events table.

I have also tried scopes but Laravel doesn't seem to like a scope attached to a belongsTo relationship.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have found that I can get the correct results and query if I use a many-to-many polymorphic relationship. The only problem is that the ComponentEvent really only has one related AircraftFlightEvent or AircraftMaintenanceEvent (depending on the value of component_events.event_type).

AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    Relation::morphMap([
        'flight' => \AircraftFlightEvent::class,
        'maintenance' => \AircraftMaintenanceEvent::class,
    ]);
}
```

AircraftFlightEvent and AircraftMaintenanceEvent:

```
public function ComponentEvents()
{
    return $this->morphMany('ComponentEvent', 'event');
}
```

ComponentEvent:

```
public function AircraftFlightEvent()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('AircraftFlightEvent', 'event', 'component_events', 'id', 'event_id');
}

public function AircraftMaintenanceEvent()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('AircraftMaintenanceEvent', 'event', 'component_events', 'id', 'event_id');
}
```

The only problem is that when calling $component_event->AircraftFlightEvent (or maintenance) it returns a collection that contains a single instance. I just need the single instance, not a collection because it'll always only ever be one model.

I've tried using morphOne but it won't generate the correct SQL. It thinks event_type is a column in the opposite table. It doesn't include the check for the value of component_events.event_type at all.

If in the end I have to live with it returning a collection that contains one object, fine ... but it sorta defeats most of the purpose of defining a polymorphic relationship in the first place if I can do it right.

Comment: You can use `polymorphic-relations` for this situation Christopher.
Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations.
In that case `Comment` has two different types, `posts` and `videos`, and here you have a `ComponentEvent` with `AircraftFlightEvent` and `AircraftMaintenanceEvent` types

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good cause for a Polymorphic relationship. But as you mentioned the Laravel documentation helps you return many records, whereas you only have a need to match one record, and naturally the Laravel community has already thought of that. There is a relationship which is not covered in the regaular Laravel docs which is called `morphOne` and is available in [Laravel Api Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOne.html).

To implement this relationship your `ComponentEvent` model should have a function like so:

```
 public function event()
 {
    return $this->morphTo();
 }
```

And both your `AircraftFlightEvent` and `AircraftMaintenanceEvent` models should have:

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->morphOne(\App\ComponentEvent::class, 'event');
}
```

(you can extract this to a trait if you like)

Keep in mind that the second parameter in the `morphOne` relationship is used to match the column prefix for your `component_event` table. So when using `'event'` Laravel will look for the `event_id` and `event_type` columns in the table.

Now when you have a `$componentEvent` all you have to do is call `$componentEvent->event()` and you will have a single instance of your `AircraftFlightEvent` or `AircraftMaintenanceEvent` models and not a collection.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Understood but what if I want to have a AircraftFlightEvent and a AircraftMaintenanceEvent method in my ComponentEvent model so that I'm being explicit about what I'm trying to retrieve from it?

Comment: The only other thing that I can suggest would be change you switch statement function to `public function AircraftEvent()
{
    return ($this->event_type === 'flight') ? $this->AircraftFlightEvent() : $this->AircraftMaintenanceEvent();
}` sorry for the bad formatting, I can't seem to fix it in a comment.

Comment: That's a problem too because there are more than just 'flight' and 'maintenance' event types. Only the 'flight' and 'maintenance' types have corresponding models.